# How to Include a Variable in the File Path of a Copy-Item cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, filepath, file-copying

Im currently trying to copy a file from one computer on my network to all of the currently online computers on my network. my code as it stands is this:

```
Copy-Item -path '\\PTFGW-061403573\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start 
Menu\Programs\StartUp\startupScriptV3.ps1' -Destination 
'\\$onlineComputers\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp'
```

and currently im getting this error

```
Copy-Item : The network path was not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -path '\\PTFGW-061403573\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\S ...
```

it works if i run each individual computer through the pile path but i want to be able to use my variable to make my code more modular and future. currently my variable ($onlineComputers) holds about 78 computers but this is bound to change in the future. how can i get this to work and is there a better way to do this? Am i not calling each individual item in my variable with how its currently set up, if not how would i go about doing that?

Comment: You need to test if the source path to that file can be found. If so, iterate over the other computers with `$onlineComputers | ForEach-Object` and first test each one if it is reachable (see [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection). If you can reach the machine, try to copy the file to the desired path.

Comment: im not 100% that i understand what your saying but its given me an idea.

Comment: $204computernames = Get-ADComputer -searchbase $sb -filter * | ?{$_.name -like "ptfg*-061*"} | select name
$onlineComputers = $204computernames |Where-Object { Test-Connection $_.name -Count 1 -Quiet }

Comment: this is how i get my variable if that helps, im pretty sure now that it is the reason my code doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you need a loop to test if the computer is on-line before trying to copy a file to it. Also, I guess in your code `$onlineComputers` is a collection of computer names and you cannot use that for constructing the destination path.

Try:

```
$fileToCopy = '\\PTFGW-061403573\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\startupScriptV3.ps1'

# $sb is the OU location to search in as DistinguishedName like "OU=Computers,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL"
(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $sb -Filter *).Name | ForEach-Object {
    # put the computername from the $_ automatic variable in a variable of your own, because when 
    # you hit the catch block, inside there this $_ is the Exception object and no longer the computer name.
    $computer = $_
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $destination = "\\$computer\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
        try {
            # -ErrorAction Stop makes sure also non-terminating errors are handeled in the catch block
            Copy-Item -Path $fileToCopy -Destination $destination -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Could not copy to computer '$computer': $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$computer' is off-line"
    }
}
```

<sup>If needed, you can expand on the `-Filter` to only look for computers with a certain known string in their name like `-Filter "Name -like 'ptfg*-061*'"`. Using `-Filter *` gives you all computers in the OU specified in `-SearchBase`</sup>